# ¿Con que formato se rellena un campo datetime-local?

Tags: html, datetime, symfony, twig

Cual es la manera correcta de rellenar un campo tipo `datetimne-local` ?

Estoy pasando la fecha desde el controlador a un twig. Cual es el formato que se le debe dar para que rellene un input de ese tipo con la fecha que yo tengo?

si le paso la fecha tal que así `{{ fecha|date('Y-m-d H:i') }}` o cualquier otro formato que se me ocurra, la console me dice lo siguiente:

> The specified value "2020-Feb-26 UTC14:0" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias poder setearlo de la siguiente manera:

```php
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{ fecha|date('Y-m-d\\TH:i') }}" min="{{ fecha|date('Y-m-d\\TH:i') }}" max="{{ fecha|date('Y-m-d\\TH:i') }}">
```